# Pick up desired content from mysql table column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table and a column. The column contains the data like below

```
<!--:en-->some content<!--:-->
<!--:zh-->概况<!--:-->
<!--:dr-->some content<!--:-->
<!--:cp-->some content<!--:-->
```

I am only interested with the content between `<!--:zh--><!--:-->`. How can I fetch this content using mysql `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(content, '<!--:zh-->' ,''), '<!--:-->', '') 
FROM tableName  
WHERE content  
LIKE('<!--:zh-->%<!--:-->')
```

Check this link [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/013d5/1/0)

Comment: oppsss. Thought that it does not matter but it does. I have Chinese character between this and it does not work with the Chinese characters

Comment: Use CONVERT function CONVERT(content USING latin1) to match data on both side

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE "<!--:zh-->%<!--:-->"
```

and parse the results to discard the ,

Answer (score 0):

I have just answered this in your [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492411/mysql-select-with-like-clause-is-not-working-chinese-characters)

```
SET @PRE = '<!--:zh-->', @SUF = '<!--:-->';

SELECT
  content,
  SUBSTR( 
    content, 
    LOCATE( @PRE, content ) + LENGTH( @PRE ), 
    LOCATE( @SUF, content, LOCATE( @PRE, content ) ) - LOCATE( @PRE, content ) - LENGTH( @PRE ) 
  ) langcontent
FROM tab
WHERE content LIKE CONCAT( '%', @PRE, '%', @SUF, '%' );
```

The desired result is in column langcontent

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caf58/17/1)