# Mysql Select with LIKE clause is not working Chinese characters

Tags: mysql, select

I have data stored in single column which are in English and Chinese.

the data is separated by the separators e.g.
for Chinese

```
<!--:zh-->日本<!--:-->
```

for English

```
<!--:en-->English Characters<!--:-->
```

I would show the content according to users selected language.

I made a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE content LIKE '<!--:zh-->%<!--:-->'
```

The query above works but return empty result set.

`Collation` of `content` column is `utf8_general_ci`

I have also tried using the `convert` function like below

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONVERT(content USING utf8) 
                           LIKE CONVERT('<!--:zh-->%<!--:-->' USING utf8)
```

But this also does not work.

I also tried running the query `SET NAMES UTF8` but still it does not work.

I am running queries in `PhpMyAdmin` if it does matter.

---

qTranslate did not change the database used by WordPress. Translation data is stored in original fields. For that reason there is each field containing all translations for that special field and the data is like this

```
<!--:en-->English Characters<!--:--><!--:zh-->日本<!--:-->
```

http://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/qtranslate-importer/

Comment: Never store multiple data in 1 column!

Comment: @juergend: It is stored by a Wordpress Plugin `qTranslate`

Comment: Please post your table - add some INSERT statements.

Answer (score 4):

Test table data for content

```
<!--:zh-->日本<!--:--><!--:en-->English Characters<!--:-->
<!--:en-->English Characters<!--:--><!--:zh-->日本<!--:-->
<!--:zh-->日本<!--:-->
<!--:en-->English Characters<!--:-->
```

followed by

> I have data stored in **single column** which are in English and
>   Chinese

and your select should look like this

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE content LIKE '%<!--:zh-->%<!--:-->%'
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caf58/17/1) (also with demo how to get the special language part out of content)

```
SET @PRE = '<!--:zh-->', @SUF = '<!--:-->';

SELECT
  content,
  SUBSTR( 
    content, 
    LOCATE( @PRE, content ) + LENGTH( @PRE ), 
    LOCATE( @SUF, content, LOCATE( @PRE, content ) ) - LOCATE( @PRE, content ) - LENGTH( @PRE ) 
  ) langcontent
FROM tab
WHERE content LIKE CONCAT( '%', @PRE, '%', @SUF, '%' );
```

as stated in [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) and follow the example of

```
SELECT 'David!' LIKE '%D%v%';
```

Comment: You're completely right. The OP was missing a pair of percent signs in his `LIKE` statement.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed, your queries seem to be fine, so I'd look somewhere else. This is something you can try:

I'm not sure about chinese input, but for japanese, many symbols have full-width and half-width variants, for example: "hello" and "ｈｅｌｌｏ" look similar, but the codepoints of their characaters are different, and therefore won't compare as equal. It's very easy to mistype something in full-width, and very difficult to detect, *especially* for whitespace. Compare " " and "　".

You are probably storing your data in half width and querying it in full width. Even if one character is different (especially spaces are difficult to detect), the query will not find your desired data.

There are many ways to detect this, for instance try copying the data and query into text files verbatim, and view them with hex editors. If there is a single bit difference in the relevant parts, you may be dealing with this problem.

Comment: it has nothing to do with what you mentioned, look at my answer and the sql fiddle demo and the edited question too

Comment: It was just another suggestion for a problem I get all the time. Sorry you found my answer to be so bad.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using MySQL, you can use wildcards in LIKE:

- % matches any number of characters, including zero characters.
- _ matches exactly one character

Here's an example search for values containing the character 日 in the `content` column of your table:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `content` LIKE '%日%'
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to reproduce the problem. The query is OK, I have got the result, even using `SET NAMES  latin1`.

Check the content of the field, possible there are beginning/ending white spaces, remove them firstly, or try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE TRIM(content) LIKE '<!--:zh-->%<!--:-->'
```

---

Example with your string -

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  column1 VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
  ('<!--:en-->English Characters<!--:--><!--:zh-->日本<!--:-->');

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%<!--:zh-->%<!--:-->';

=>  <!--:en-->English Characters<!--:--><!--:zh-->日本<!--:-->
```

Comment: Tried the query but with no luck `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0051 sec )`

Comment: Can you show some lines from the table? Just a few INSERT statements to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Search fails because of the way you store data.
You are using utf8_general_ci collation, which is tailored to fast search in *some* European languages. It is even not so perfect with some of them. People tend to use it just because it fast and they don't care about some search inaccuracy in, say, Scandinavian languages. 
Change this to big5_chinese_ci or some other Chinese - tuned collation.

UPD. 
Another thing.
I see, you use a kind of markup in your DB records.

```
<!--:zh-->日本<!--:-->
<!--:en-->English Characters<!--:-->
```

So, if you're searching for Chinese, you may just use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE content LIKE '<!--:zh-->%'
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE content LIKE '<!--:zh-->%<!--:-->'
```

Comment: if so, why does this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caf58/17/1 returns the desired result?

Comment: In which encoding/collation it stores data for table and variables? If it is converted to the same encoding - no problem. BTW, nice tool. Thanks for showing it to me.

Comment: the data in the field is written by a wordpress plugin and can be processed by itself. So the reason of not finding is the missing % at begin and end. thats all. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce202/2/1 Noone gave this clue and he didn't test it

Comment: His data samples are not like the ones you use in sqlfiddle. You concatenated EN and ZH records.

Comment: and thats what is his case "I have data stored in single column which are in English and Chinese". FAQ qTranslate http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3#p14 (last post on page) ;o)

Comment: Just got another link (german) but you can have a look at the data from one field http://www.drweb.de/magazin/praxis-mehrsprachige-website-mit-wordpress-und-qtranslate/ all are concatenated

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask what version of MySQL you're using? From what I see your code seems fine, which gets me thinking you're not running the most up to date version of MySQL.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.